# Need to get the content of a boundary box in a separate image

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

I wrote a piece of code which draws a boundary box around an object of interest.
Next step is to resize the boundary box so I have a little bit of background with it.
Now I want to get the contents of the boundary box in a separate image so I can process this region of interest. The code I wrote is:

```
findContours(Sal11, Objects, CV_RETR_LIST, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_NONE);

       //Kleine contouren verwijderen.
       for(unsigned int i = 0; i < Objects.size(); i++)
       {
           if (Objects[i].size() > 250 && Objects[i].size() < 500)
               Objects2.push_back(Objects[i]);
       }

       cv::Mat Person=input;
       // Bounding Box
       for(unsigned int i = 0; i < Objects2.size(); i++)
       {
           Rect rect = boundingRect(Objects2[i]);
           Point pt1, pt2;
           pt1.x = rect.x - 100;
           pt1.y = rect.y;
           pt2.x = rect.x + rect.width + 100;
           pt2.y = rect.y + rect.height;
           rectangle(input, pt1, pt2, CV_RGB(0,0,255), 1);
           cout << rect << endl;

           Rect rect2;
           Person = input(rect);
       }
```

`rect2` does not do a thing right now but I want it to be the content of `rect`. with `pt1` and `pt2` I resize the bounding box. The code is meant for real-time processing.

Comment: Not sure I fully understand what you are asking, but can you not just instantiate rect2 using a constructor that takes the pt1 & pt2?

Comment: What I am doing now is drawing a boundary box around an object of interest which I detection autonomous. I resized the box because I need more than just the object. Then I draw the resized box in an image. I need the content of this resized boundary box in a separate image. Hope this clarified my question

Comment: So you want to construct a new `Rect` object to represent the boundary around this extended object? What does the `Rect` class look like? We need more code as I don't know what objects like `Person` are and what functions like `input(Rect)` or `boundingRect(Objects2)` do.

Comment: It feels like you should perhaps have `Rect rect2 = rectangle(input, pt1, pt2, CV_RGB(0,0,255), 1);` but again we don't know what the method `rectangle` does.

Comment: When I do a cout I get:  [82 x 68 from (248, 51)]

Comment: rectangle is a opencv functions to draw a boundary box.

Comment: A cout on what object? Rect2? Can you please post the code for Rect as I have no idea how it is converted to string or how `<<` has been overloaded for that class.

Comment: edited my post. This is the only code which is relevant to this problem I think

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I afraid you get two definitions messed up together: drawing on image and cropping region of interest from image.

1) Function 'rectangle' in OpenCV is drawing a rectangle on given image.

2) 'Person=input(rect)' creates sub image of 'input'. You can work with it just like you work with 'input' image. Just remember that it is not performing any copy of image, i.e. it is done in O(1) and any change of pixel of 'Person' will change appropriate pixel of 'input'.

Comment: I want Person to be Person=input(rect2), because now I miss the background of the object. That's the reason I need to get the contents of the resized boundary box

Comment: ... I guess I am missing what you are trying to get. Person=input(rect2) is already giving you content of image in some bounding box. What else do you need to know? How to change size of rect or something?

Comment: What i've got is: Person = input(rect), what I want it to be is: Person = input(rect2). But before I can do that I need to give rect2 some input/values. And I want it to be the coordinate and size of the resized boundrybox rect.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood the question. Well there are plenty of methods to change size of rect. The one I would use is: Rect rect2 = rect + Size(100,100) + Point(-50,-50); rect2 &= Rect(0,0,Person.cols,Person.rows);

Comment: This will means that size 'rect2' bigger than size of 'rect' by 50 pixels in each side. And second command is to be sure that you are not trying to access values outside of the image.

Answer (score 0):

Creating a `Rect` from the new `Point`s you have made should be as simple as doing:

`Rect rect2(pt1, pt2);`

This [api](http://docs.opencv.org/java/org/opencv/core/Rect.html) states you can construct a rect from two points like this.

Is that what you wanted to do?

Also, I would consider creating your new points using the constructor like so:

```
Point pt1(rect.x - 100, rect.y);
Point pt2(rect.x + rect.width + 100, rect.y + rect.height);
```

Comment: No, this does not work. Need the content of the boundary box as an input for further processing

Comment: It works!!! I tried the Rect rect2(pt1, pt2); but got a segmentation error. So I searched further but because of my rect.x - 100 it becomes less then 0